# Alpha texture edges problem

Tags: texturing

I have a problem with alpha texture in my scene. the edges of the of the letters are disappearing. (see photos). I am a beginner in Blender...
Not sure why does it happen. the alpha texture is 8000x8000 png.
[image]

Comment: If you are using "Alpha-Clip" as your Blend Mode in your Material Properties, you can change the Clip Threshold. That might allow you better control over how much of the edges get clipped. No guarantees though, a lot depends on the detail (specificity) of the alpha texture itself.

Comment: Thanks! I will try and let you know if it helped! much appreciated

Comment: I tried, it's the maximum use of it, no change...... but thanks!